# Load JavaScript Files from the resources/js Directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm working on a Laravel 7 project that's on GitHub. I would like my .js files to be pushed to GitHub, too, but since they're in the public/js/ directory, they're not.

Currently, I'm loading my .js files like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

The asset() function is loading my JS files from the public/js/ directory. How I can load them from **resources/js/** instead?

Answer (score 0):

i don't recommended load files from the resources/ folder, to use that files you have to use [npm](https://nodejs.org/es/) in the console, with the command`npm run dev`, this command compiles all your assets defined in the file webpack.mix.js into your public/ folder

```
npm run dev
```

if you want to know more about compiling assets, you should see
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#introduction

Comment: Where do you recommend loading them, not including public/js/?

Comment: only load files from your public/ directory, if you want to load files from resources use the command, and the files in resources compiles in public, so now yo can used

Comment: you can read more about compiling assets here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#introduction

Comment: definitely compile them into /public/js/    alternatively just put the file inside the /public/js folder and use the asset helper shown above.